# What is the difference between these two ways of appending tuples to a list

Tags: python

I have the following code that breaks:

```
l = []
tup = ('a', 'b')
l = l + tup
```

which gives the below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list
```

but the below code runs

```
l = []
tup = ('a','b')
l += tup
```

without any error.

I always thought l+= is the same as l = l +

What is going on over here?

Comment: The first operation fails because it executes `l+tup` first which calls `__add__` which isn't supported, the latter calls `__iadd__` the implementation of which allows this so they are not implemented necessarily the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `l = l +` is calling `list`'s `__add__` method, whilst `l +=` is calling `__iadd__` method, which is addition in place (equivalent to calling `extend` method).